# Disable Past Months & Year using Jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using following code for disabling past dates, but not working

```
    $("#card_expiry").datepicker({
            format: "mm-yyyy",
            startView: "months",
            minViewMode: "months",
            changeMonth: false,
            changeYear: false,
            stepMonths: 0
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried `minDate: 0` or `startDate: new Date()`?

Comment: Worked : startDate: new Date()

Answer (score 1):

```
minDate:0
```

minDate

Type: Date or Number or String

Default: null

The minimum selectable date. When set to null, there is no minimum.
Multiple types supported:

Date: A date object containing the minimum date.

Number: A number of days from today. For example 2 represents two days from today and -1 represents yesterday.

String: A string in the format defined by the dateFormat option, or a relative date. Relative dates must contain value and period pairs; valid periods are "y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for weeks, and "d" for days. For example, "+1m +7d" represents one month and seven days from today.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#card_expiry").datepicker({
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        startView: "months",
        minViewMode: "months",
        changeMonth: false,
        changeYear: false,
        stepMonths: 0,
        minDate: 0,
    });
```

Comment: WORKED: startDate: new Date()

Answer (score 0):

```
   Following code works for me:

  $("#card_expiry").datepicker({
            format: "mm-yyyy",
            startView: "months",
            minViewMode: "months",
            changeMonth: false,
            changeYear: false,
            stepMonths: 0,
            startDate: new Date()
        });
```